# pyodbc does not seem to process CASE statements from ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, case, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc for connection to Oracle (64bit) and for some reason the below Case sql statement works in SQL Developer but encounters an error in pyodbc.

```
select xx, yy, zz,
case
    when zz > 10000000 Then 'A'
    when zz < 10000000 Then 'B'
end as casetest
from xxyyzz where zz is not null;
```

> Error: Execution failed on sql: 'select xx, yy, zz, 
>       case 
>                when zz > 10000000 Then 'A' 
>            
>   when zz < 10000000 Then 'B' 
>       end as casetest 
>       from xxyyzz where zz is not null; class 'pyodbcError' returned a result with an error set

Keep in mind that the above statement works in Sql Developer. I have tried joins, where, with, partition, decode statement and they all work well with pyodbc. It seems CASE does not work.

I suspect the driver I use might be the issue. The driver i use is DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12102}.

Thanks any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simplify and isolate the problem (especially with helpful errors like that one).  For example, does it work without the case expression?  By taking that out you might find that multi-line statements don't work...

Comment: Multiline statements do work as with the other queries i have tried with pyodbc. It does not help that pyodbc error is a decidely vague error.

Comment: Regardless, I collapsed the Case statement into one line. Tried in sql developer that it works but failed in pyodbc with this error. ('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended\n\x00ƿ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ue2a0댞y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00览견ƿ\x00\ue4d0댞y\x00谨견ƿ\x00ꌘ겱ƿ\x00趔彛\x00\x00\uf578걋ƿ\x00\ue2a0댞y\x00\ue2a4댞y\x00谨견ƿ\x00\uf578걋 (933) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Try a different driver? :(

Comment: I think it might be a library issue or driver problem. Btw, the above error cannot be right. I copied the working statement from sql developer into my code.

Comment: And the error seems to alternate between that mess of an error and pyodbc error. Yea I might have to try a different driver. Do you know where i might find the latest driver?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/python-with-database-11g.html and https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/ ?

Comment: Having the exact same problem and not finding any help out here on the interweb. I'm switching to DECODE. Fortunately, my comparisons are straight "equals to", so I can easily move it to DECODE.

Comment: @JohnChase I solved the problem by using cx_Oracle instead of pyodbc when connecting to Oracle. pyodbc is not good for Oracle. so now i am using cx_oracle to establish connection  to Oracle and pyodbc to connect to MS SQL Server. Kinda dumb to be using two packages but you can run all kinds of statements using cx_Oracle instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DECODE`, maybe it'll help:

```
select xx, yy, zz,
  decode(sign(zz - 10000000 ), 1, 'A', -1, 'B') casetest
from xxyyzz where zz is not null;
```

By the way, code you wrote presumes that `zz` can't be exactly `10000000`; is that correct?

---

P.S. ah, right, you said you tried `DECODE`. Sorry, didn't see it on time.

Comment: i masked the data tables due to confidential but the conditions is to check if zz is more than 10000000 or if zz is less than 10000000. Which is where DECODE fails as DECODE only allows for equality of conditions. The strange thing is that statement is perfectly valid in sql developer but fails when read by pyodbc which leaves me perplexed.

Comment: That's why I used **sign** with DECODE. I don't know why CASE won't work; it is on the market for long time so I guess it *should* be supported. If it is not, well, try something else.